# msi GS66 Stealth 11UH touchpad doesn't work on ubuntu20.04 and 21.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad

Somehow my pc(msi GS66 Stealth 11UH) touchpad doesn't work. I tried some  current kernel is 5.12.19-051219-generic. Does anyone solved this?

FYI, I could work touchpad once in Ubuntu20.04or21.04(I forgot, sorry),kernel5.11.0-25 but after some installation of another software and firmware, touchpad stopped working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this for upgrading to ubuntu21.10, kernel5.11.0-33. I cannot clean install from USB for any reason, I upgraded from ubuntu21.04.  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/
FYI, on kernel 5.11.0-31 touchpad didn't work.

Comment: it's working, but lagging a lot, do you have solution ?

Comment: not sure why lagging, you tried ubuntu22 too?

Comment: Yes, ubuntu 22, it moving smoothly at the begining, after 2 secs it moving not smooth, but jerkily.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue, it seems the new version of GS66 equipped with some new hardware, probably need to wait couple of Ubuntu updates